# efficient content proposal and referencing member references in Xtext

Tags: java, antlr, xtext, eclipse-emf, xtend

I used the newly introduced great feature of xtext 2.8.3, the synthetic tokens, but what I'm facing is

1. a lag with the proposals
2. a validation error

> Couldn't resolve reference to EStructuralFeature 'name'.

the problem is that the proposal didn't show up unless I typed the first character.
I've overridden the method below but does not work very well

```
complete_BEGIN(EObject model, RuleCall ruleCall, ContentAssistContext context,
        ICompletionProposalAcceptor acceptor)
```

and my scope

```
override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    if (reference.name == "eType") {
        val elements = Lists.newArrayList(EcoreUtil2.getRootContainer(context).eAllContents.filter(EClassifier))
        return Scopes::scopeFor(elements)
    } else if (reference.name == "feature" && context.eContainer instanceof Instance) {
        var eClass = (context.eContainer as Instance).getEType()
        Scopes::scopeFor((eClass as EClass).EStructuralFeatures)
    }
    super.getScope(context, reference)
}
```

and my grammar that uses them is

```
InstaceFeature:
feature+=[ecore::EStructuralFeature] value=ValueLiteral;
//
Instance returns ecore::EClass:
    {Instance}
    name=ID '=' 'new' eType=[ecore::EClass]
    (BEGIN
    features+=InstaceFeature*
    END)?;
```

what I want to perform is the `feature` in `InstanceFeature` would contain the list of the structured features of the `eType=[ecore::EClass]` in the `Instance` object.

Comment: This line is probably the reason for your lag: `val elements = Lists.newArrayList(EcoreUtil2.getRootContainer(context).eAllContents.filter(EClassifier))`. If, for example, your EClassifiers can only be at the root of your model you wouldn't have to traverse the whole using `eAllContents`

Comment: Thanks Franz, your right, but I have basically my eclassifiers contained in an epackge, but I think this is not the issue, I think that I'm doing something wrong with my grammar, may be I should have defined my Instance in another way ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here. Could you provide a self contained example (i.e. minimal grammar that I can copy&paste into my Eclipse and a snippet of your desired target DSL)?